# Trying to split campaign names by days between start and end date in EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Raw]

I am trying to split campaign names by day.
For Example : For each campaign, I want to see x number of rows where x = the number of days between the start and end date

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Formula will not be the best way to do this.  This should be done with vba

Answer (score 0):

Formula solution

(Some adjusting to the original date in order to reduce the number of days for demonstration only)

In `E2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$4)/(C$2:C$4-B$2:B$4>=COLUMN($1:$1)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]